# How to change the MOCK implementation of a service per unit test

Tags: jestjs, angular-spectator

How to change the implementation of a mock depending on the test.

this is the code I am trying to unit test.

```
open(url: string, target: string = '_self'): void {
 const win = this.document.defaultView?.open(url, target);
 win?.focus();
}
```

And below my unit test

```
const MockDocument = {
  location: { replace: jest.fn() },
  defaultView: undefined
};

const createService = createServiceFactory({
  service: RedirectService,
  providers: [
   { provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: MockDocument }
 ]
});
```

My strategy is to set defaultView to **undefined** for the first test. And inside the next test, I would change the implementation to contain the open function, like this

```
const defaultView = {
open: jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation((url: string, target: string = '_self') => {
    url;
    target;
    return { focus: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {}) };
  })
};

const MockDocument = {
 location: { replace: jest.fn() },
 defaultView: defaultView
};
```

How do I change the implementation depending on the test?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

```
it('should not call "open" if defaultView is not truthy', () => {
  spectator.service.openFocus('foo');

  expect(mockDocument.defaultView).not.toBeTruthy();
});

it('should call "open" if defaultView is truthy', () => {
  //CHANGE THE IMPLEMENTATION HERE...
  const spy = jest.spyOn(mockDocument.defaultView, 'open')

  spectator.service.openFocus('foo');

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set defaultView up as a variable and change the variable speed test.

```
let defaultView: any;

const MockDocument = {
    location: { replace: jest.fn() },
    defaultView};

beforeEach(() => {
    ...
});

it('should not call "open" if defaultView is not truthy', () => {
    defaultView = undefined;
    expect(mockDocument.defaultView).not.toBeTruthy();
});

it('should call "open" if defaultView is truthy', () => {
    defaultView = {
        open: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation((url: string, target: string = '_self') => {
            url;
            target;
            return { focus: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {}) };
        })
    };

    const spy = jest.spyOn(mockDocument.defaultView, 'open')

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: please take a look at the edit. Can you tell concretely how the call to a different implementation would look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: it's not updating the `defaultView`, which is still `undefined` when I put a breakpoint.

Comment: Maybe you also need to do this with mockDocument?